# Getting Memory Error while installing tensorflow in raspberry

Tags: software-installation, python-3, raspbian-buster, qemu

Memory Error while installing tensorflow in raspberrypi-buster
[image]

Comment: **DO NOT** post pictures of text - post text!

Comment: I vaguely remember I had some sort of memory error when installing TF. Then I was advised to expand swap memory and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow will install on a RPi but it has been a bit of a nightmare. The instructions of the TensorFlow site are [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install), but I had to hunt around for version that would install since the standard one would not.

That said I've just tried an install on a new 8G Rpi4 using `pip3 install tensorflow` and it installed straight off, so I presume TensorFlow have fixed the previous Rpi install problems. Just make sure you use pip3 and not pip.I haven't run tensorflow on the 8Gb Pi but it has run ok on a Rpi 3 previously.

The installed version was given as

> Successfully installed protobuf-3.0.0 tensorflow-0.11.0